# Space remove from String

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    char array[]="Arijit Saha Student";
    spaceremover(array);
    getch();
    return 1;
}

int spaceremover(char a[]){
    int i;
   // printf("L=%d",strlen(a));
    char final[strlen(a)+1];
    int count=0;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i++)
    {
        if(a[i]!=' ')
            final[count]=a[i];
        count++;
    }
    final[count]='\0';
    int j=0;
    for(j=0;j<strlen(final);j++)
    printf("%c",final[j]);
    // printf("\n%s",final);
    return 1;
}
```

With this example code the output is `Arijit.Saha`, but my desired output is `ArijitSahaStudent`.
Why am I getting the wrong output?
Where the . is coming from?

Comment: This probably belongs on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @VladLazarenko Really? I thought SO is for programming issues and CR is for reviewing code. Then what kind of questions belong here?

Comment: The '.' is probably just junk data leftover from something else. Your biggest problem is that `count` is being incremented no matter what. You should put curly braces around `final[count]=a[i];` and `count++` so `count` only increments when a letter is added to the array. Currently, when it gets to a space, nothing is added to the `final` array at that position

Comment: `char final[strlen(a)+1];` : is this legal in C?

Comment: @anishsane It is with C99 compliant compilers I believe.

Comment: @anishsane: This is called VLA (for Variable Length Array). Basically, compiler allocates such arrays on stack as in `alloca()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not incrementing count correctly.  It needs to be in the if loop. This might be easier for you to see if things are indented correctly.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
  char array[]="Arijit Saha Student";
  spaceremover(array);
  return 1;
}

int spaceremover(char a[]){
  int i;
  // printf("L=%d",strlen(a));
  char final[strlen(a)+1];
  int count=0;
  for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i++)
  {
    if(a[i]!=' ')
      final[count++]=a[i];
  }
  final[count++]='\0';
  int j=0;
  for(j=0;j<strlen(final);j++)
    printf("%c",final[j]);
  // printf("\n%s",final);
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The error is here:

```
if(a[i]!=' ')
    final[count]=a[i];
count++;
```

The `count++` should be included in the `if`, so:

```
if(a[i]!=' ') {
    final[count]=a[i];
    count++;
}
```

Note: It is considered good programming practice to always use curly braces after `if` statements.

Comment: +1 nice spotted. It just shows how important is the proper indentation of the code.

Answer (score 2):

In the for loop you increase count even if `a[i] == ' '` .
So when `a[i] == ' '` you only increase count but doesn't set `final[count]` to anything.

I assume you ment to write:

```
if (a[i] != ' ')
{
    final[count] = a[i];
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the loop, the count should increase if a[i] not equal to space

`if(a[i]!=' ')
      final[count]=a[i];
count++;`

```
if(a[i]!=' ')
final[count++]=a[i];
//count++;
```